# python selinium CSS_SELECTOR error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to automate login to a web cite with selenium and python.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox ()
driver.get (page)
```

this line

```
WebDriverWait (driver, 10).until( EC.presence_of_element_located (By.CSS_SELECTOR("#top-login-uname")))
```

produces the following error

```
WebDriverWait (driver, 10).until( EC.presence_of_element_located (By.CSS_SELECTOR("#top-login-uname")))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

the argument to CSS_SELECTOR seems to be correct...
I able to find the line with Firefox search line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you should use

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#top-login-uname")))
```

Note that `EC.presence_of_element_located()` should accept tuple of `by` and `value`

`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` is generated because `By.CSS_SELECTOR` stands for a simple string `'css selector'`